# Ubuntu Not Starting - Urgent Help Required

Tags: 14.04

After i run this command  `sudo apt-get remove libpam-smbpass`
**Ubuntu doesn't start.**
i see the Ubuntu logo with dots below and then a blank screen after that.
if i close lid and open again i see button labeled with [OK] and nothing happens.
please help.

Comment: If you hit ctrl-alt-f1 keys do you see a command prompt ?

Comment: yes, i can see command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

- Press the 3 keys:  ctrl+alt+F1 : it will switch to a login screen (or not depending when the boot stops: then see the 2nd part)
- Type your login and password : it will open a terminal
- in the terminal, type `sudo apt-get install libpam-smbpassword`
- Press ctrl+alt+suppr to reboot

---

- If it doesn't work, reboot again and just after bios, press ESC key : it will show the Grub menu in which you can choose "advanced option" then  "recovery", then "root console".
  In this console ,  type the above command .

Comment: i did the following steps but still no progress.